# How can I retrieve information from deleted CloudFormation stacks using boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, boto3

I have a boto3 script that basically collects certain information from CloudFormation stacks with the state - CREATE_COMPLETE. However, I would also like to retrieve information from stacks with the DELETE-COMPLETE status. According to the docs, I can only do this by providing the stack ID. Unfortunately I don't know the Stack IDs. Is there any way I could retrieve information without the stack IDS or probably is there a way to obtain the deleted stack IDs?
P.S. I can see the deleted stacks and their IDs on the AWS console by selecting the "Deleted" filter option but I would like to get this information using boto3.

Answer (score 1):

You can call [list-stacks](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html#CloudFormation.Client.list_stacks) with a stack status filter to get the details of all the deleted stacks.